# How do I disable the Chrome Sign-In popup?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I disable the Chrome "feature" that causes the following sign-in popup to pop up?

[image]

Comment: Looks like HTTP auth to me. The website you’re navigating to demands it. It cannot be disabled.

Comment: Try any JavaScript blocker to block it.

Comment: You're probably going to have to script the login, too.

Comment: I have the same problem on my own site! It's not a popup I implemented myself but a google chrome feature! Moreover, it doesn't even work! I wish I could programmatically disable it!

Comment: This has been answered in https://superuser.com/a/1538362/195452 in a more useful way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way to prevent this popup from appearing is adding the site to the trusted sites in your browser.

On top of this it is key to set your browser security settings (internet options) to the following settings:

Enable automatic logon (I opted for intranet only since it is an intranet site)
[image: Automatic login settings]

in the advanced tab enable the integrated windows authentication

[image: Windows auth]

This solved my issue for me.
Be sure to restart your machine after setting these configs in order for them to take effect.