# Disable chrome "sign in as" popup

Tags: google-chrome

When I'm using Google Chrome and visit a website where I have more than one password stored, it shows a pop up that saying "sign in as".  It's getting annoying, especially when you only go to check one thing, and asks this each time.

I have disabled the option that says "auto login" in the password section.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this page at the Tech Junkie website https://www.techjunkie.com/chrome-auto-sign-in/ "To disable auto sign-in in Google Chrome..."

Comment: @vssher that link doesn't address the question. The TechJunkie article is in reference to sign-in on the Chrome browser itself, not general websites.

Comment: Related [How to disable Google One Tap sign-up prompts?](https://superuser.com/q/1414410/152004)

Comment: This worked for me https://superuser.com/a/1773215/142948

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been annoyed by the same thing for a while on several sites, mainly Twitter and Instagram, and I recently did some research to find out what was causing it.

I learned that the "Sign in as" pop-up is caused by sites using the [Credential Management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API). There doesn't seem to be a way to disable it in Chrome's settings, but if you happen to be using an userscript extension such as Tampermonkey, you can use a simple script to make the API inaccessible, getting rid of the pop-ups while retaining all other Chrome's password storing functionality.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Disable Credential Management API
// @include      *
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

delete Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator).credentials;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try disabling the pop-up in settings of chrome. or simply , go to advance settings, then site settings-> notifications -> remove -> disable sites can ask... -> under allow, remove all the unnecessary stuffs there.